# Recognize number from video

Tags: java, opencv, capture

Im working on a project now and there is something I dont know how to start work on.
I have a webcam connected to my computer and aiming to a screen that streaming number every few minutes.
I need to capture those number using my webcam... 
How can I recognize those number ?
I tought to use openCV but I guess there is a better solution.

thanks

btw, I tought to work on this project in java but if you have a better solution I will glad to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called **OCR** (Optical Character Recognition). I would recommend to you **Google tesseract**, a project on OCR that has even bindings for Python (language that I recommend for its simplicity in fields as machine learning and OCR).

- Main project: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr
- Python bindings: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract

Here there is an example from the python bindings:

```
<!-- language: python -->

import Image
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

Of course there are bindings also for **java**. Precisely it is provided by [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll check all of that out ! :)